# How to know the collection has changed by user in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I'm listing a collection with one check box and description. Now when user will click on submit button I want to validate that user should have clicked on at least one checkbox. I know there is an event "change" in collection but am not sure how to use it.

I want this collection should have a property of boolean type to check 
whether the collection is changed or not.

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on , collection.on('change', function(){})

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your prompt response.
I know i can use change event of collection. I wonder am correct in my solution. Here is my code. Note am registering the event after my view is rendered because on default I change some values.

```
complienceListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#complienceList'),
    initialize: function () {
      complienceList.bind("reset", this.render, this);     
    },
    render: function () {
        complienceList.each(function (complience) {
        $(this.el).append(new complienceListItemView({ model: complience }).render().el);
        }, this);
        complienceList.on('change', function(){isDirty = true;})
        return this;
    }
});

var isDirty = false;
```